# Accessing 'preview feature' properties of enterprise application in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

My subscription has preview feature enabled.
I created application in Microsoft Azure.

To access **claims** preview feature of application edited the URL by adding '?feature.claimseditorpreview=true'

Also added some custom claims to 'Claims (preview)'.

Now I would like to access the preview feature of application's claim using REST api.

[image: Application with preview feature enabled]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

You can retrieve the list of **claims mapping policy** that is applied to a Service Principal/Azure AD Enterprise Application.

To create **claims mapping policy**, please try the below query in [**Microsoft Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies
{
"definition": [
"{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\", \"ClaimsSchema\": [{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"assignedroles\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName\"}, {\"Value\":\"900\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/SessionDuration\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"assignedroles\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"appRoles\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/nameidentifier\"}]}}"
],
"displayName": "Test Claims Policy",
"isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

***Claims mapping policy will be created like below:***

[image]

To **assign the created policy to a Service principal**, execute the below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/servicePrincipalObjectID/claimsMappingPolicies/$ref
{
"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/claimsMappingPolicies/PolicyID"
}
```

A response of **204** will be returned if successful:

[image]

To retrieve the **claims mapping policy**, switch to beta:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/servicePrincipalObjectID/claimsMappingPolicies
```

[image]

***Unfortunately, listing Attributes & Claims for an Azure Service Principal is not possible.***

Please refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-beta#methods) which describes the possible methods on Azure Service Principal.